# Calling action from slice removes slice from my store

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have an app that I'm converting from "normal" redux to redux toolkit using slices. I've already converted one of my reducers, and it works fine. I've written a second slice, and before I switch over my old actions to the new actions, the app runs (but of course when I call my actions they don't do anything).

Here is the current state of the slice file:

```js
export const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'data',
  initialState: defaultDataState,
  reducers: {
    clearStudyData(state) {
      state.series = [];
    },
    // ... other actions ... 
  },
});

export default dataSlice.reducer;
```

And here is the first place I've tested swapping action creators:

```js
export const handleStudyDataMessage = (message: MessageEvent): ThunkAction =>
  dispatch => {
    const data = JSON.parse(message.data);
    const { series: receivedSeries }: BackendStudyDataPayload = data;
    if (receivedSeries === null) {
      dispatch(dataSlice.actions.clearStudyData())  // <--- action from the slice
      // dispatch(clearStudyData);     <--- old action creator
    } else {
      const str = 'A message was received on the study data channel, with series:';
      dispatch(updateStudyDataFromBackend(receivedSeries));
    }
  };

// the old action creator
export const clearStudyData = { type: ActionType.CLEAR_DATA };
```

When I replace the call to my old action creators with a call to one of my new slice actions, the app crashes because the slice is no longer in the store!!! I open redux devtools, and the state is missing my object.

With the old action creator:

[image]

After swapping action creators (code as pasted above)

[image]

What is going on here?!

Here is the other working slice in my app:

```js
const metaSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'meta',
  initialState: defaultMetaState,
  reducers: {
    tabChanged(state, { payload }) { state.activeTab = payload.tab },
    errorReported(state, { payload }) {
      const { error } = payload;
      const { code, message, recoverable } = error;
      if (error && !recoverable && state.statusTimer) {
        clearTimeout(state.statusTimer);
      }
      state.error = error;
    },
    statusUpdated(state, { payload }) { state.status = payload.status },
    statusTimerReset(state, { payload }) { state.statusTimer = payload.timer },
    clearError(state) { state.error = null; },

    systemInfoReceived(state, { payload }) {
      return { ...state, ...payload.info };
    },
    scannerStatusUpdated(state, { payload }) { state.scannerStatus = payload.status; },
    licenseStatusUpdated(state, { payload }) { state.licenseStatus = payload.status; },
    feedbackSet(state) { state.feedback = true; },
    dispatchError() { console.error('Dispatch Error'); },
  },
});

export const { /* all the actions */ } = metaSlice.actions;

export default metaSlice.reducer;
```

Here's the store setup

```js
const rootReducer: Reducer<AppState, Action> = combineReducers({
  settings, meta, settingsMeta, data,
});
const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware);
const storeEnhancers = [middlewareEnhancer];
const composedEnhancer = composeWithDevTools(...storeEnhancers);
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composedEnhancer);
```

Comment: Can you show your other reducers and your store setup code?  Also, just to check, is this by any chance an Electron app?

Comment: Is there any error message in console when app crashes after action is dispatched? Also, what is the value of `ActionType.CLEAR_DATA`?

Comment: @AjeetShah the action type is just a string, `'CLEAR_DATA`. The error comes from a selector that tries to call a property on the `data` state: `Cannot read property series of undefined: > export const selectDataSeries = createSelector(selectDataState, data => data.series);`. So it's simply failing because, as I've said, there's no data reducer. Nothing helpful.

Comment: Is it possible to create a sandbox?

Comment: @markerikson see update. (Ajeet, no it is not)

Comment: @AjeetShah thanks. Given that I already have a working slice, and have used toolkit in other apps, I don't think a working sample really helps.